# Exchange Server 2010 double booked rooms

Tags: exchange-2010

I am having an issue with meeting rooms being double booked. I have allow conflicts set to false and I'm not sure why this is still happening. Does anyone know of a setting that would override allow conflicts?

```
[PS] C:\Users\chawkins\Desktop>Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity "indentity" | fl


RunspaceId                          : 27a25e8c-7584-4133-8fea-36b1f0b78fa5
AutomateProcessing                  : AutoAccept
AllowConflicts                      : False
BookingWindowInDays                 : 180
MaximumDurationInMinutes            : 1440
AllowRecurringMeetings              : True
EnforceSchedulingHorizon            : True
ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours         : False
ConflictPercentageAllowed           : 0
MaximumConflictInstances            : 0
ForwardRequestsToDelegates          : True
DeleteAttachments                   : True
DeleteComments                      : True
RemovePrivateProperty               : True
DeleteSubject                       : True
AddOrganizerToSubject               : True
DeleteNonCalendarItems              : True
TentativePendingApproval            : True
EnableResponseDetails               : True
OrganizerInfo                       : True
ResourceDelegates                   : {}
RequestOutOfPolicy                  : {}
AllRequestOutOfPolicy               : False
BookInPolicy                        : {}
AllBookInPolicy                     : True
RequestInPolicy                     : {}
AllRequestInPolicy                  : False
AddAdditionalResponse               : False
AdditionalResponse                  :
RemoveOldMeetingMessages            : True
AddNewRequestsTentatively           : True
ProcessExternalMeetingMessages      : False
RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications : False
IsValid                             : True
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do users have rights to put a meeting directly on the calendar of the resource through the Calendar tab in Outlook?  I've seen this happen when admin assistants and others have actual author/etc. permissions to the calendar.  They place it on the calendar after someone has already sent a meeting invite and gotten an accept from the resource booking.

Comment: I was just able to create a meeting with one test user and then create a meeting at the same time in the same room with another test user. These are normal users and I am adding the meeting through the calendar tab in OWA. Are you asking if users can log into the room in OWA and create meetings?

Comment: I mean are you booking it as a "resource" or as an attendee?

Comment: As far as I can tell just as an attendee.

Comment: That's the problem then.  Resource mailboxes should only be booked as a "resource" not an "attendee".

Comment: So, should normal users not be able to book rooms? I'm confused.

Comment: They should book them as resources not attendees.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZKmx0MGCy8

Comment: Are you booking rooms directly on the room's calendar?  Or are you using the schedule meeting/invite attendees feature in Outlook/OWA?  The auto-attendant only works if the room is "invited" as a room/resource to the meeting, not if it is listed as an attendee or if the meeting is directly scheduled on its calendar.